# Loading Sentry from CDN with `defer` attribute, and avoiding Uncaught ReferenceError when initializing

Tags: javascript, sentry

I am loading Sentry from CDN with the `defer` attributed as per [Using Defer](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/install/cdn/) in the Sentry docs.

I have a subsequent `script` tag, that initializes Sentry using `Sentry.init`, as per the [Usage & Configuration](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/install/cdn/#usage--configuration) docs.

This results in an `Uncaught ReferenceError: Sentry is not defined` as `Sentry.init` is executed before Sentry has time to load due to the `deferred` attribute.

What is the best way to initialize Sentry when using the `defer` attribute, so that errors that may occur in other scripts (which are also using `defer`) are not lost?

The code extact:

```html
<script defer
            src="https://browser.sentry-cdn.com/7.42.0/bundle.tracing.replay.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-1l6jGKe2vLyGsLU9U92iHngOrra5b0R13LKJan+gGw9ZdY7iK2ayrwusH0QaMjWI"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<script>
Sentry.init({
  dsn: "https://sentryPublicKey@o410200.ingest.sentry.io/123456",
  release: "{{ SENTRY.dsn }}", //from Django Context
  integrations: [new Sentry.BrowserTracing()],
  tracesSampleRate: {{ SENTRY.traces_sample_rate }} //from Django Context,
});
</script>

// all other script tags are after Sentry and have a defer attributed (as per the docs).
```

Should I just extract the initialization logic into a separate JS file and then load it right after the Sentry CDN script tag also using `defer`, or are there better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a `load` event listener to the Sentry [script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement) as follows:

```js
myScript.onload = () => {}
```

Implementing this would look like this:

```html
<script
  id="sentry-script"
  defer
  src="https://browser.sentry-cdn.com/7.42.0/bundle.tracing.replay.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-1l6jGKe2vLyGsLU9U92iHngOrra5b0R13LKJan+gGw9ZdY7iK2ayrwusH0QaMjWI"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>

<script>
  document.getElementById("sentry-script").addEventListener("load", () => {
    Sentry.init({
      dsn: "https://sentryPublicKey@o410200.ingest.sentry.io/123456",
      release: "{{ SENTRY.dsn }}",
      integrations: [new Sentry.BrowserTracing()],
      tracesSampleRate: "{{ SENTRY.traces_sample_rate }}"
    });
  });
</script>
```

By using the defer attribute, you're directing the browser to parse the entire HTML document before loading the script. In this context, the script will only execute, and Sentry will initialize, once the full Sentry resource has been completely loaded.

Comment: I do not think this will work. The `load` event is fired [after all page resources and dependencies have loaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event).  As such any errors in scripts that come after the Sentry script and before the load even which initializes Sentry will be lost and not seen in Sentry.

Comment: @garyj The code is attaching a listener to the script, rather than the window, so it won't wait for the entire page to load. You are looking at the window load event in MDN.

Comment: I see what you are saying, I missed the fact that you attached the the `onload` to the script. So would this guarantee that the Sentry.init would execute (and initialize sentry) before any other scripts in the page that follow `sentry-script` and also use defer are executed?

Comment: @garyj Yes, will wait for the script to load, and then `Sentry.init` will be executed.